# Pass variable to wordpress php function

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, stylesheet

I have a variable from the wordpress theme options for the color scheme selected:

```
$themecolor
```

I want to use the following code to properly include the stylesheet:

```
<?php /* enqueue color stylesheet */ 

function add_color_style() {
wp_register_style( 'color_style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/'.$themecolor.'.css', 'all' );
wp_enqueue_style('color_style');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_color_style'); ?>
```

The problem is that the $themecolor variable is not being passed into the function, so the output ends up like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='color_style-css'  href='http://bbmthemes.com/themes/expression/wp-content/themes/expression/css/.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Instead of like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='color_style-css'  href='http://bbmthemes.com/themes/expression/wp-content/themes/expression/css/lime.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

What is the proper way to pass that variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `global $themecolor` within your function or just use `$themecolor = get_option('themecolor');` within that function if that option comes from the `wp_options` table.

You can also do this...

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() use ($themecolor) {
    wp_register_style( 'color_style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/'.$themecolor.'.css', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('color_style');
});
```